# Javascript error with XPages application

Tags: javascript, proxy, xpages

I look after an application based on XPages that some users are having trouble with. There is a random Javascript error on some of the pages that only resolves itself when the pages are reloaded. I managed to get a screen shot of the error message on Internet Explorer - it's the warning triangle you see when there's a JS error.

Clicking on the message in IE, I am told there is a syntax error in the following URL:

http://cdncache2-a.akamaihd.net/loaders/1036/l.js?aoi=1311798366&pid=1036&zoneid=74570

I have no idea what this is?! It's not a resource that is linked to on my application. The XPage app is on an internal company server, runs fine for me but users in Germany regularly get this.

I tried to find out about the URL but haven't found anything solid on google yet. Some sites hint at Proxies however. So I checked my IE settings for LAN and found I am not using a proxy, and the option to bypass a proxy for LAN addresses is greyed out. I got the people in Germany to confirm they also have the same setting as me.

Can anyone give any clues as to why this JS error is coming up on the application?

Comment: sounds like the proxy execute this js code for all websites and that this is used to cache pages in the proxy to avoid unneccesary http request to the internet. it could be that there is something wrong with the js code or that the code is not compatible with the xpages code.

Comment: Thanks for the input. The application is correctly being recognised in IE as a Locla Intranet application and the users, like me don't have a proxy server specified

Comment: The script looks pretty cool! It injects a lot of interesting stuff f.e. advertisment, embeds flash files, has geolocation features and does much more with the current HTML page

Comment: Yeah I could see it does some interesting stuff, but why would an xpage that has no mention of this fail to load properly when this file has a syntax error in it? We didn't include the file in the XPage application

Comment: Maybe a browser addon? Do you have a clean computer with a clean browser to check if this script is added?

Comment: Yes, the computer I am using right now is a new build with nothing other than windows, Lotus Notes 8.5.3 and IE8 installed. Everything is working as expected, the site is reliable and I never see these JS errors. I will be asking the IT guys in Germany to check the machines affected by this problem - but there are more than 1 affected which is why I wondered if it was a proxy issue or something over there.

Comment: Can Browser addon's affect the loading of a page though?? If this is down to an addon, why would it affect the current page and break it - you know how IE simply stops working as soon as a JS error is encountered?

Comment: Does your website serve adverts? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akamai_Technologies

Comment: Try using another browser like firefox or chrome and see if you get the same problem. There is probably a malware problem.
Try scanning the computer with spybot (http://www.safer-networking.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tool you want to use is [CURL](http://curl.haxx.se/). Using that you get the source code of the JS that gets loaded. If the code messes up the DOM then local JavaScript will fail. I would second Sven's suspicion that it is an addon. The question is: a planned or an unplanned one. You might want to entertain a HTTP Debugger to see what is going on on the wire. [TCPMon](http://ws.apache.org/commons/tcpmon/) from Apache is free and cross platform. [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) is free but Windows only and [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) is Shareware cross platform. The later two can debug HTTPS too. Let us know the findings

Comment: Thanks all for the input.  I haven't had chance to fully investigate it yet but I did look at the JS file in question and found a bit in the middle of it that mentions savings-slider.com which is definitely nothing to do with the application I look after. I have asked the users in Germany to confirm if they have a browser addon and do a full virus scan to make sure they haven't got any adware installed.